# How do I test code that runs on update for IOS apps?

Tags: ios, xcode

My app contains code that must modify the DB in the documents directory on update of the app (because the structure of the DB has changed between versions).

The loading of the new version of the app to a phone via xcode works fine, and runs the code correctly. However I'm concerned that this may not exactly mirror what happens when updating via the app store on the phone.

In order to properly test that this code runs correctly when a user updates their app through the app store, I gather it used to be possible to load the app via an ad hoc distribution, which would install it as if it were an update from the app store. The (rather old) instructions for that are here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2285/_index.html

I attempted this, by exporting the ad hoc .ipa file and dragging onto the device in ITunes, only for it to tell me the app is already installed. The .ipa file contains the updated app and it has a higher version number than the one installed on the device.

Do I need to do this another way? Or is loading the app via xcode sufficient to emulate what the user's phone will do when updating the app?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried TestFlight? https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: I think Testflight is the official way for testing the release purpose. Indeed I had the same issue while I was working with CoreData and new datamodel version (test the database migration). I used to test with iTunes and the ipa file too, but now I use Testflight.